# Null/black pixels of javaxt.io.Image being rendered

Tags: java, image

So I have skewed an Image in Java using javaxt.io.Image. However, when I tried rendering it using the getBufferedImage() method, it showed up as a rectangular image. Whichever pixels should not have been rendered due to skewing were being rendered black.

Any idea on how to render the image without those null pixels? Currently checking every pixel whether it is black or null is taking a toll on my system. Basically, I want a method to render a non rectangular javaxt.io.Image.

I have tried searching how to render javaxt.io.Image but nothing relevant showed up.

Comment: Change their alpha values to 0? `int pix = (0<<24)|(255<<16)|(255<<8)|255`

Comment: @CraigR8806 that does not mean that the upper left pixel would not be a null one using which I am rendering the BufferedImage

Comment: Please try to explain what you mean differently.  That sentence doesn't make sense and I'm not sure what you are trying to convey

Comment: @CraigR8806 You see, I want to render an Image without the null pixels. After "cropping out" the null pixels, I want the upper left corner non null pixel to be used as a location for the image for rendering